# Access a locally stored file from my Grails app?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I need to have my grails application access a locally stored pdf file for reference purposes. I have an absolute path to a spot on a local server, and the app will be running on the same network.

I'm not sure if it is better to have the user input the filename into a text field (subject to user error) and then store it in the database, which I could then make a link to appending it to the path as in:

```
<a href="${resource(dir:'/serverName/locationName/pdfs',file:'FILENAME_with_Ext.pdf')}" target="_new">pdfFile</a>
```

but this doesn't seem to work, as it won't find the file and I get a 404 error

The other thing I was thinking is that it might be easier to have the user upload the file , if there is one, because there might not always be a file. I think this might be the better way to go, but I don't know where I would store the files. Would I make a folder in the Web Application directory and store all the files there?

Thanks for any input you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

The resource directive is relative to the web apps root, so i don't think it will be able to access anything outside that.

I'm not sure what you mean by there might not always be a server - there is always a server that the app runs on.  If you mean database server I guess that is technically correct, although you could always use H2 or some other in-memory database at the very least.

The [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles) have a pretty good section on file uploads.  You could follow that and have it save the files to any directory you have access to - mapped or network or local.  Probably best to do it outside the web app so you don't overwrite when you redeploy.  Save the filename and whatever description you need to show the users.

Then to access you will probably need to set up some sort of aliasing in your web server (tomcat, etc).  So lets say you stored the docs at `/var/myWebApp/uploads` then you create an alias with the web server setup so that `/uploads/` points to `/var/myWebApp/uploads` and serve them up as `http://www.myserver.com/uploads/uploaded.pdf`

I don't know what security concerns you have for this site but you might want to obfuscate the file names if you are worried about people looking through the uploads directory, and don't allow that directory to show itself as an index and list the files it contains.

***EDIT***

Very basic example

```
//class
class MyClass {
    String fileDescription
    byte[] fileDocument
}

//form
<g:uploadForm action="save">
    Description <g:textField name="fileDescription" />
    <input type="file" name="fileDocument" />
    <input type="submit" 
</g:uploadForm>

//controller
def save = {
    def myClass = new MyClass(params)
    myClass.save()
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing "not always going to be a server" was referring to the pdf file.  [A dangling participle!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4vf8N6GpdM)

Comment: Correct, There will not always be a file.

Comment: Understood - I think that points even more to doing the upload.  I think it looks much better to an end user to let them pick from a list of files, or do a auto-populate rather than to just let them enter a filename and then go look for the file.  Eliminates some user frustration and they see fewer "We can't find what you want" messages.

Comment: @Kelly - OK, the thing I am having trouble understanding is how to upload the document inside another form, because I am having them choose the document to upload at the same time that they are choosing other information. Once they hit the submit button, I want the document to be saved along with the other information. I was able to get the data into the database as blob form, but I am not sure what you mean by 'saving the filename and whatever description' - how would I do that part?

Comment: You can have any other standard form fields in the same upload form.  All the <g:uploadForm...> tag does is add the enctype="multipart/form-data" to the regular form tag.  So if you need to you could add a field for the user to enter a description or a title for the uploaded document; then save that in the same controller action you use to save the uploaded document.  If you are using data binding to do it all it's dead simple.  I'll update my original answer with a small sample.