# How to open a file from Grails app using <a> tag?

Tags: grails

This is my first Grails project & I can't seem to do this very simple thing! I am trying to display a list of PDF forms in one page that I have saved under a folder called **forms** under `my_project/grails-app/views/forms` and want to open the PDF form in a new window when clicked.

In my `.gsp` file I am trying to access the forms like this:

```
<a href="${resource(dir:'forms',file:'form_one.pdf')}" target="_blank">Form #1</a>
```

But that's giving me a 404 error.

I have found couple of solutions like [this one](https://grails.slack.com/archives/questions/p1445615634001306) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10728697/1081016) (which is very similar to mine)...but first of all, i don't need to upload/download the file. Second, i don't need to render the file either. All I want to do is just click the link and open the PDF file in a new window/tab. Am I saving the PDF files in a wrong place? Please help!! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your file/directory into `grails-app/assets` so that you have `grails-app/assets/forms/form_one.pdf` then you can use the `resource` tag like this:

```
<a href="${resource(dir: 'forms', file: 'form_one.pdf')}" target="_blank">Form #1</a>
```

The `grails-app/views` directory is used for views rendered by controllers, where as the `grails-app/assets` directory is used for static and pre-processed assets.